# If I permanently delete my account, will my messages in my friend's timeline be deleted?

Tags: facebook

If I permanently delete my Facebook account, will the messages I sent in my friend's timeline be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

If you delete your Facebook account permanently, it will ask whether to delete related post and other things. If you then select yes, it will not show any posts on your friends timeline. If you do not agree, then your posts will be available. Other users, however, can't find your profile/identity anymore.